# Group by in Pandas to find Median

Tags: python, pandas

I have a properties dataset. I would like to know the median price according to several attributes as follows:
`suburb`,`rooms`,`bathrooms`,`type`,`car`,`age`. Then I want to add a new boolean column to state if the property is overpriced or not.

sample of my dataframe(the original dataframe has 180 suburbs):

```
house=pd.DataFrame({'subrub':['BALWYN NORTH','ARMADALE','ARMADALE','PASCOE VALE'],
                 'price':[1350000.0,800000.0,1250000.0,680000.0],
                'rooms':[3,4,7,2],
                'bathroom':[1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0],
                'type':['h','t','t','u'],
                'car':['2.0','1.0','4.0','1.0'],
                'age':[59.0,69.0,12.0,14.0]})
```

So far I have grouped by suburbs. I know I can use `median` to find the median, but I am not sure how to approach the other attributes. Any tip would be helpful. Thank you,

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for groupby in pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```py
def over_price(elements):
    median = np.median(elements)
    return elements > median 

house["OverPrice"] = house.groupby(["subrub","rooms","bathroom","type","car","age"])["price"].transform(over_price)
```

Comment: @leena What is a median of categorical data?

Comment: for example, like the columns `suburb` and `type`